# asp.net: How to find repeater div in backend?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I use repeater to display records fetching from database, especially I use div tag to display html content stored in datatable. But I don't know how to find the div in backend. In Repeater_ItemDataBound event I can use

```
Control divControl=e.Item.FindControl("divControl");
```

to get it but it does not have innerHtml property to set html content. Does anyone know how to get it as a div control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) defines the methods, properties, and events for all HTML server control elements not represented by a specific .NET Framework class.

So if its a server control you can simply use:

```
HtmlGenericControl divControl = e.Item.FindControl("divControl") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

Comment: You'll aslo need the divControl to be runat="server"

Answer (score 1):

To find the DIV in the code behind, you'll need to add the `runat="server"` tag to the DIV.

If you're going to do that, you might as well just use a `Panel`, as it outputs a DIV anyway.

After doing the above, you should be able to find it like this:

```
Panel panel = (Panel)Repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("Panel1");
```